# Getting error while setting a data into recycler view

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting 2 data from firebase and setting them in a card view in recycler view they are

- name
- nodename

there is no problem with the "name" data but my "nodename" data is not being set in the text view

the error message that I am getting

```
No setter/field for node found on class com.Loopchat.com.Mychats_Model
```

my model class

```
package com.Loopchat.com;

public class Mychats_Model {

public Mychats_Model(String name, String nodename) {
    this.name = name;
    this.nodename = nodename;
}

Mychats_Model(){

}

String name, nodename;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getNodename() {
    return nodename;
}

public void setNodename(String nodename) {
    this.nodename = nodename;
}
}
```

this is my Firebase data base structure
[image]

myAdapter Class

```
package com.Loopchat.com;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
 import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

 import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
 import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;


 public class Mychats_Adapter extends 
 FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Mychats_Model,Mychats_Adapter.myViewHolder> {

 private static final int MSG_TYPE_LEFT = 0;
 private static final int MSG_TYPR_RIGHT = 1;


/**
 * Initialize a {@link RecyclerView.Adapter} that listns to a Firebae query. See
 * {@link FirebaseRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
 *
 * @param options
 */
public Mychats_Adapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Mychats_Model> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Mychats_Model model) {

    holder.name.setText(model.getName());
    holder.node.setText(model.getNodename());


    holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(holder.node.getContext(),Chat2.class);
            intent.putExtra("nodename",model.getNodename());
            holder.node.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });



}

@NonNull
@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mychats_item, parent, false);
    return new myViewHolder(view);

   // if (viewType == MSG_TYPE_LEFT) {
   //     View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_left, parent, false);
   //     return new myViewHolder(view);
   //} else {
   //     View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_item, parent, false);
   //     return new myViewHolder(view);
    //}
}

class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView name,node;


    public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

      name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.namedoc);
 //     node = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nodename);
      node = itemView.findViewById(R.id.d);

    }
}
}
```

XML of my item for my recycler view

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
         android:elevation="6dp">
    
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:id="@+id/imagedic"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagedic"
        android:text="Username"
        android:id="@+id/namedoc"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

   
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/d"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/namedoc"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="98dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagedic"
        android:text="Nodename"
        android:textSize="15dp" />


</RelativeLayout>




 </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

my MainActivity

```
package com.Loopchat.com;

   import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

   import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

      import android.content.SharedPreferences;
       import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

     import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

     public class MyChats extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView rvc ;
Mychats_Adapter mychats_adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_chats);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref",MODE_PRIVATE);

    String myname = sharedPreferences.getString("username", "User");
    Toast.makeText(this, myname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("TAG", "onCreate: "+myname+"Chats");



    rvc = findViewById(R.id.rvc);

    rvc.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Mychats_Model> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Mychats_Model>()                  .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(myname+"Chats"), Mychats_Model.class)
                    .build();

    mychats_adapter = new Mychats_Adapter(options);
    rvc.setAdapter(mychats_adapter);

}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mychats_adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mychats_adapter.stopListening();
}
}
```

[image: this is the main DB]

Comment: Are you getting the right values in the views? Have you also tried to set the fields in class private?

Comment: one of the value which is "name" is good and works but the other value does not work, the textview stays blank

Comment: But if you try to use `Log.d("TAG", (model.getNodename());` inside `onBindViewHolder`, are you getting the correct value?

Comment: no, When i Try to do this -- 
Log.d("lol", model.getName());
                Log.d("lol", model.getNodename());

i only the the "name" value but not the "nodename" Value

This is the error i get " FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.Loopchat.com, PID: 22358
    java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message "

Comment: Are you then sure, that all children under that node contain a field called `nodename`? Can you check that?

Comment: there is only one child under the main node, of which i have given the photo !

Comment: In that case, please show a more detailed database schema, in which we can the parent nodes, as well as the code that you're using to create the references and the adapter.

Comment: I added MY MainActivity Code

Comment: Hey @AlexMamo I solved the Problem, It was Just a Typo in the node name!, Thankyou so much for helping btw